# Parsing data and transferring it between views with SwiftyJSON and AlamoFire

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object that is held in an Array. I'm using SwiftyJSON but the program is not behaving as I expected.

This is the array:

```
var GamesList = [JSON]();
```

The array holds my 2 JSON objects:

{
  "game_type" : "TRADITIONAL",
  "game_player_winner" : "",
  "game_state" : "STARTED",
  "self_left" : "2",
  "self_right" : "1",
  "self_name" : "test2",
  "opponent_right" : "1",
  "opponent_name" : "test1",
  "game_guid" : "153fac87-bfc4-367f-41fa-944753dc32c8",
  "game_idle_time" : 755858,
  "opponent_left" : "3"
}, {
  "game_type" : "TRADITIONAL",
  "game_player_winner" : "",
  "game_state" : "STARTED",
  "self_left" : "2",
  "self_right" : "1",
  "self_name" : "test2",
  "opponent_right" : "1",
  "opponent_name" : "johannesswart",
  "game_guid" : "153fac87-bfc4-367f-41fa-944753dc32c9",
  "game_idle_time" : 755858,
  "opponent_left" : "3"
}]hier is je gamestate: Optional({
  "game_type" : "TRADITIONAL",
  "game_player_winner" : "",
  "game_state" : "STARTED",
  "self_left" : "2",
  "self_right" : "1",
  "self_name" : "test2",
  "opponent_right" : "1",
  "opponent_name" : "testuser",
  "game_guid" : "153fac87-bfc4-367f-41fa-944753dc32c9",
  "game_idle_time" : 755858,
  "opponent_left" : "3"
}

I create a new JSON object and fill it with a value of object 1 from the Array:

```
var gameState : JSON?;
self.gameState = GamesList[1];
```

When I print the entire self.gameState object to the console all is well and it looks like what I expected. However when I want to just use 1 value of this JSON object I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried with:

```
self.gameState["game_type"].string;
```

And:

```
var foo = JSON(self.gameState);
```

But this is both not compiling. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can see where this can be frustrating, but this is actually a pretty simple fix.
I had your same problem a while back when doing work with AlamoFire.

I can see why it's not compiling though, you are trying to retrieve a `key` out of an `Array` like:

```
self.gameState["game_type"]
```

but the `Array` type doesn't have `key:value` pairs, simple it is accessed via indexes:

```
self.gameState[1]
```

**Step 1**

So instead of an array, get your JSON into a dictionary. After that, follow these steps:

Make sure that your JSON data is being stored in a `dictionary`, like:

```
let jsonData: [String:String] = //your JSON
```

(use the var keyboard if you will be manipulating data in `jsonData`.

**Step 2**

After your JSON data is stored in a `dictionary`, simply do:

```
let gameState = jsonData["game_type"]!
```

You should not have a problem after that.

I hope I was able to shed some light, please comment if anything was unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It unfortunately did not help me solve the problem. I get an error when trying to do: self.gameState[1]. Xcode says: Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type 'int'